# How to use Xquery 3.1 (new features like Maps and Arrays) in JAVA (in XQJ or in any other way)?

Tags: java, xml, xquery, xqj

What I already tried :-

1. Saxon XQJ
2. XQJ with BaseX
3. XQJ with Sedna
4. XQJ with eXist

I was not able to use XQuery 3.1 in any one of them. Any clues ?

Comment: Since Saxon, BaseX, and eXist all support XQuery 3.1 (at least in part; there may be some gaps), the first guess has to be that you're doing something wrong in the way you're calling them.  Without more details, no one is going to be able to tell you exactly what it is that you're doing wrong.

Comment: XQJ simply does not support XQuery 3.1 as of now, so will have to use the native interfaces for the three XQuery processors you mention. If you want XQJ to support this new standard you might want to ping Charles Foster, the maintainer of this module. Of course, actually paying him to implement this feature greatly improves the chances he actually got time for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say in detail what you did and how it failed, and then we can tell you what you did wrong. In Saxon 9.8, XQuery 3.1 is supported by default: try `-qs:"map{1:2}(1)"` from the command line. XQJ itself has no support for the new XQuery 3.1 data types, and in Saxon I would recommend using the s9api API in preference: but XQJ will run queries using 3.1 syntax provided you don't need to use the new data types in the query's input or output.

You've tagged the question with xquery-update but your question gives no clue as to why.